# Support modern emojis in a custom android keyboard

Tags: java, android, custom-keyboard, ime

I'm building android keyboard application and I want to support modern emojis on the app.
Is there is a library or a simple way to implement emojis with android [KeyboardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView)

I've tried some ways to implement modern emojis, but I did not find any library to do that

Comment: What were the ways you have explored so far?